# Gcc-Ada configuration error

Tags: ada

I downloaded gcc-ada-4.3.4.tar.gz when configure gave an error configure: error: cannot find install-sh or install.sh in . ./.. ./..

gcc version=4.3.4 using fedora16

Comment: Why not install gcc-gnat using your system's graphical package manager?

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora 16 you can do `yum install gcc-gnat`. This will install the appropriate GNAT version for your system.

If you really want to build it yourself, you have to install all dependencies first. You can find them easily.